# Low Variables in cartthrob arithmetic

Tags: cartthrob, low-variables, math

Hi is there any posibility to get this working?

```
{exp:cartthrob:arithmetic expression="{option_price_numeric} -({option_price_numeric} * {exp:low_variables:single var='early_bird_discount'} / 100)"}
```

In {exp:low_variables:single var='early_bird_discount'} is 30 in this example
I'm getting an "undefined variable" error and I know this is correct but I don't know how exactly get the right result for this

**Update**:

Using the first option Rob Sanchez suggests gives me the following error: **Unparsed EE tags in expression, check parse order.** Perhaps it is important for you that the tag is nested into several tags in an embed template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events" require_entry="yes" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
  {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {categories show_group="24"}
      {options}
        {if option_value == "{embed:option}"}

          {if category_id =="160"}
            {if "{event_early_bird_date format='%U'}" >= "{current_time format='%U'}" && "{exp:low_variables:single var='siteA:early_bird_discount'}" >"{embed:another_discount}"}
{!-- ##### --}
              {exp:cartthrob:arithmetic expression="{option_price_numeric} -({option_price_numeric} * {early_bird_discount} / 100)"}
{!-- ##### --}
            {if:else}
              {exp:cartthrob:arithmetic expression="{option_price_numeric} -({option_price_numeric} * {embed:another_discount} / 100) + {embed:membrr_price}"}
            {/if}
          {if:elseif category_id =="161"}
            [....]
          {/if}
          [...]

        {/if}
      {/options}
    {/categories}
  {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Update 2**

I figured out the problem I think. early_bird_discount is a low variable of siteA but I'm trying use this variable on siteB so using {early_bird_discount} does not work here. Is there any possibility to get the global variable from siteA on siteB?

Answer (score 2):

You could try two things:

One is to set this particular Low Variable as Early Parsed (in the variable settings). Then you can call it like this:

```
{exp:cartthrob:arithmetic expression="{option_price_numeric} -({option_price_numeric} * {early_bird_discount} / 100)"}
```

Or you could try adding parse="inward" to the arithmetic tag:

```
{exp:cartthrob:arithmetic parse="inward" expression="{option_price_numeric} -({option_price_numeric} * {exp:low_variables:single var='early_bird_discount'} / 100)"}
```

Comment: Yep. And I'd recommend the first option.

Comment: I have updated the description because there is still an error. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: You should open up cartthrob/libraries/Math.php and `var_dump($expression);` in the evaluate function. If you do that, you should be able to see which unparsed tag is the culprit.

Comment: You can also enable template debugging and look up the cartthrob:arithmetic tag, to see what the actual opening tag looks like. If the LV is parsed, you can rule that out as the culprit.

Comment: if I use `{early_bird_date}` this is the culprit. If I use `{exp:low_variables:single var='siteA:early_bird_discount'}` I get the following expression: **199.00 -(199.00 * M20o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr / 100)**

Comment: Does anybody has an idea what the problem is? Would be great

Comment: I don't see {early_bird_date} in your example. If that's a LV, and it's not parsed, then it's not set to be parsed early.

Comment: {early_biry_date} is a variable of the channel

Comment: But I don't see early_bird_date in your arithmetic examples? If I had to venture a guess, I'd say that your "advanced" conditional statement is to blame. You might want to try the IfElse plugin there.

Comment: I figured out the problem I think. early_bird_discount is a low variable of siteA but I'm trying use this variable on siteB so using {early_bird_discount} does not work here. Is there any possibility to get the global variable from siteA on siteB?